# open a new windows in IE browser via selenium without 403 error

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

I am clicking on web Element in IE Browser through Selenium it opens a new window with error 403 while clicking by user even in selenium browser opens a new tab with no error.Please suggest how to deal with this scenario

Comment: This error (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage. You could  contact the website if you're sure you have permissions to access. Then, clear the browser cache files, and re-open new browser window.

Comment: First of all, are you able to reach desired website manualy?